# Problems with replacing characters in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to make a "morse code translator" program, but I have a problem.

I want something like this: when we enter a morse code it should translate it to English and when we enter English text it should return a morse code and I used "Ⓐ" instead of A.

My problem is in translating morse code to English.

When I enter ".--- " it should show "Ⓙ", but it shows "Ⓐ" because the first parts of them are similar.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Here are the parts of the code that I have a problem in:

```
.replace(".-", "Ⓐ"))
.replace(".---", "Ⓙ"))
.replace("a", ".-  "))
.replace("j", ".---  "))
```

Comment: You need to invert the first two `replace` calls

Comment: well, you can't spell ".---" without ".-" . you'll need to divide the morse signs with a separator, or run some sort of sophisticated grammatical/vocabulary test on the result;

Comment: what is the input string? do you have a character delimiter?

Comment: write a parser for that, it's starts from right and goes to left and replaces the morse symbols to letters (put it into a ByteArray), the replace method will loop the entire string on every call (It's not so performant), The parser loops only one time and will be faster.

Comment: @G.Vitelli this will just lead to the same problem

Comment: @Stultuske you are right, he need to put a space or other separator to split the morse signs

Comment: Guys , It's the first program that I'm making in java , Can you help me more ?
I mean How should I code it??
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of:

this one:

```
.replace(".-", "Ⓐ"))
```

occurs also here:

```
.replace(".---", "Ⓙ"))
```

Consider about 2 strings:

.-.-.-.-.-

.---.---

When you use first replace (ex. replaceAll), then strings will looks like:

ⒶⒶⒶⒶⒶ

Ⓐ--Ⓐ--

Cause .- is inside first and second string.

To avoid that you can use Regex for example

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Or invert the replaces, but this is bad practice (there are so much combinations, that you can't check everything.
Good idea is also to split everything into mors code blocks, then check for EQUALITY 1:1 for these strings.

So you will have

```
1: .-
2: .-
3: .-

1: .---
2: .---
3: .---
```

Then when you will check for equals:

.- is equal to .-? true, replace

.--- is equal to .-? false, don't replace

Something like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mors = ".-- .- .--- .- .---";
        String[] morsBlocks = mors.split(" ");
        String[] morsDecoded = new String[morsBlocks.length];
        decoder(morsBlocks, morsDecoded);
        for(String decoded: morsDecoded) {
            System.out.print(decoded + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("---EOT---");


    }

    public static void decoder(String[] blocks, String[] decoded) {
        for(int index = 0; index < blocks.length; index++) {
            String block = blocks[index];

            switch(block) {
                case ".--":
                    decoded[index] = "bla";
                    break;
                case ".-":
                    decoded[index] = "test";
                    break;
                case ".---":
                    decoded[index] = "omg";
                    break;
                default:
                    decoded[index] = "UNDEFINED";
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String[][] MORSE_TABLE = {
    {".-", "Ⓐ"},
    {".---", "Ⓙ"},
    {"--...", "7"},
    {"---", "O"},
    {"...", "S"},
    ...
};
```

The problem is that one should try to convert the longest sequence first, as one otherwise could never translate the longer one.

However that is still ambiguous: do you have **A7** or **J**?
Hence pauses (spaces) are very helpful in those cases.

```
// Sorting on decreasing morse length:
static {
    Arrays.sort(MORSE_TABLE,
        (pair1, pair2) -> -Integer.compare(pair1[0].length(),
                                          pair2[0].length());
}
```

And then start at the beginning and do a sequential replace:

```
List<String> results = decode(s);
if (results.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("No results");
} else if (results.size() == 1) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + results.get(0));
} else {
    System.out.println("Ambiguous result: " + results);
}

List<String> decode(String morse) {
    morse = morse.trim();
    if (morse.isEmpty()) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add("");
        return results;
    }
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String m : MORSE_TABLE) {
        if (morse.startsWith(m[0]) {
            List<String> furthers =
                decode(morse.substring(m[0].length));
            for (String further : furthers) {
                results.add(m[1] + further);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Ambiguous parsing is possible too, as shown above.